# is there a way to loop rows that meet condition to set a single range

Tags: excel, vba

I want the VBA to loop through rows in a worksheet and set a range based on the rows that meet a condition.

At the moment my code only selects the first row where the condition is true and I want all of the rows that meet the condition to be included in the set range ...

```
Sub setrng()
    Set WkSht = Sheets("Main")
    For i = 1 To 335
        If WkSht.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Y" And WkSht.Cells(i, 9).Value = "ZC" And WkSht.Cells(i, 10).Value = "N" Then

            Dim rng As Range
            With Application.Intersect(WkSht.Rows(i), WkSht.UsedRange)
                Set rng(i) = WkSht.Range(WkSht.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Count))
            End With

            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union).

Comment: Might be better to use filters to find your rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a range from ranges is best done with Union. The small problem is that you can't union something with nothing. In that case (which is the first iteration), you will have to set the collected range to the first found range. After that, use union

```
Sub setrng()
    Dim CollectedRange As Range
    Dim AddedRange As Range

    Set WkSht = Sheets("Main")

    For i = 1 To 335
        If WkSht.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Y" And WkSht.Cells(i, 9).Value = "ZC" And WkSht.Cells(i, 10).Value = "N" Then


            With Application.Intersect(WkSht.Rows(i), WkSht.UsedRange)
                Set AddedRange = WkSht.Range(WkSht.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Count))
            End With

            If Not AddedRange Is Nothing Then
                If CollectedRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CollectedRange = AddedRange
                Else
                    Set CollectedRange = Union(CollectedRange, AddedRange)
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next
    Debug.Print CollectedRange.Address
End Sub
```